# How to best reach into MongoDb Mongoose Schema objects which use lists of other objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am learning my way around MongoDB data types and the best way to use documents and Schemas through Mongoose.

I've defined a couple of Schemas for a Navigation bar object which stores the navigation items as a list, and each item is defined by a schema with the properties name, type, url, and a list of drop downs if it has any (if the type is "dropdown").

Here are those Schemas:

```
var navSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    items: [Schema.ObjectId]
});
```

is the nav object, and

```
var navItemSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: {type: String, default: "link"},
  url: {type: String, default: null},
  dropdowns: {type: [Schema.ObjectId], default: null}
});
```

is the nav item schema, but each nav item can potentially have dropdowns, and so the dropdowns is a list of nav items, which can also potentially have dropdowns. But in this case, only a few do.

Now to create the data for these objects, I have to do something like this to create a nav item, example for "home"

```
var home = new navItem({
  name: "home",
  url: "/home"
});
```

but for items with dropdowns, I have to define all the items I know will be dropdowns before defining list which includes those items, and then defining the parent item and using the list with those items I just defined. Like this

```
    var allAccessories = new navItem({
      name: "all accessories",
      url: "/accessories"
    });

    var cushions = new navItem({
      name: "cushions",
      url: "/accessories#cushions"
    });

    var cupHolders = new navItem({
      name: "cup holders",
      url: "/accessories#cupholders"
    });

  var accessoriesDropdownItems = [
    allAccessories,
    cushions,
    cupHolders
  ];

var accessories = new navItem({
  name: "accessories",
  type: "dropdown",
  dropdowns: accessoriesDropdownItems
});
```

So, I assume I'm doing that right..? My only gripe with this method is that in my nav.js file where I create this mongodb object/collection, I have to think about what items are going to be used in dropdowns of other items, and so I have to theoretically order them to be defined before the other variables are defined in the document.

But if I then want to use an item in two dropdown lists, and one of those dropdownlists I happened to have already defined above it in the document but now want to add to. I have to move the item definition above anywhere it's used,  this ruins the organisation of the document..

But I'm okay with physically indenting to keep my work organised and sorted.

My question is how do I actually access properties of objects within lists of other objects.

Straight up I define Nav as simply an object with an id, "nav" because I don't want to use its _id ObjectId to reference it all the time...? And an items array which contains the navItemsSchema objects.

But when I try to reach into these objects through mongo shell using something like

```
db.navs.find({items: {$elemMatch: {name:"home"}}})
```

Or
    db.navs.find({items: ObjectId("58d5d6df0789f718460ff278")})
Or
    db.navs.find({items:{ "name" : "home"}})

I can't get any data back.. I have successfully manage to return all objects in the collection through the node app via responding found nav in navs

```
app.get('/nav', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.model('nav').find(function(err, nav) {
    res.send(nav);
  });
});
```

But all this returns me is a data structure with object id's and not the actually data of the objects.

```
{"_id":"58d5d6df0789f718460ff287",
"id":"nav","__v":0,
"items":
    ["58d5d6df0789f718460ff278",
    "58d5d6df0789f718460ff279",
    "58d5d6df0789f718460ff286",
    "58d5d6df0789f718460ff281",
    "58d5d6df0789f718460ff282",
    "58d5d6df0789f718460ff283",
    "58d5d6df0789f718460ff284"
    ]
}
```

Could you please help me understand how I reach into these data hierarchies via say db.navs.nav("nav").items.findAll() and it lists all the items and their json?

Or is this not possible and you need to loop through all items, then. Wait, where are the objects stored corresponding to ObjectId's in the items list?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I actually figured it out myself. I was using type: [Schema.ObjectId] (ie. type was a list of Schema.ObjectIds) but I didn't know that that automatically parses the inputted list of objects and extracts just their ObjectId's and stores them, all I need to do was make the type: [] (ie. just a list) and then I can traverse my nav object simply by... Oh wait, for some reason when mongoose nav.saves my nav it becomes an object inside a list. So when I mongoose.model('nav').find(function(err, nav) {} it gives me a nav object which I need to use via nav[0].items[0].name Or I can go nav = nav[0] but I wish I didn't need to do this step? Maybe there's an answer but yes. Otherwise. This is the solution I was looking for.